# Does anyone know these candy

Tags: candy

Does anyone know  the name of this candy?
It comes in a pink wrapper with an airplane on it
[image]

Comment: Which airline / what flight you got it on might help narrow this down.

Answer (score 4):

These appear to be generically-manufactured, compressed, face towels.Its possible that the exact same packaging (or, at least, design) is used for small candies but I have not found them.

Here you go: https://www.amazon.nl/-/en/collectsound-Disposable-Compressed-Outdoor-Camping/dp/B07FFNNBHT

Comment: Woah, packing towels in the shape of candies, what could go wrong?